# Problem when scaling a tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I am using `elsarticle` class, and i need some help to scale my tikzpicture.

```
\documentclass[numbers,preprint,review,12pt,sort&compress]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
        % Node styles
        \tikzstyle{circulo_vermelho}=[fill=red, draw=black, shape=circle]
        \tikzstyle{circulo_cinza}=[fill={rgb,255: red,128; green,128; blue,128}, draw=black, shape=circle]
        \tikzstyle{circulo_verde}=[fill=green, draw=black, shape=circle]
        \tikzstyle{circulo_amarelo}=[fill=yellow, draw=black, shape=circle]
        \tikzstyle{circulo_azul}=[fill=blue, draw=black, shape=circle]
        \tikzstyle{texto}=[fill=none, draw=none, shape=circle]
        % Edge styles
        \tikzstyle{seta}=[->]
        \node [style={circulo_cinza}] (0) at (0, 5) {};
        \node [style={circulo_cinza}] (1) at (0, 3.5) {};
        \node [style={circulo_cinza}] (2) at (0, 2) {};
        \node [style={circulo_vermelho}] (3) at (3.5, 5) {};
        \node [style={circulo_vermelho}] (4) at (3.5, 3.5) {};
        \node [style={circulo_vermelho}] (5) at (3.5, 2) {};
        \node [style={circulo_vermelho}] (6) at (7, 5) {};
        \node [style={circulo_vermelho}] (7) at (7, 3.5) {};
        \node [style={circulo_vermelho}] (8) at (7, 2) {};
        \node [style={circulo_cinza}] (9) at (0, -3) {};
        \node [style={circulo_cinza}] (10) at (0, -4.5) {};
        \node [style={circulo_cinza}] (11) at (0, -6) {};
        \node [style={circulo_azul}] (12) at (7, -3) {};
        \node [style={circulo_azul}] (13) at (7, -4.5) {};
        \node [style={circulo_azul}] (14) at (7, -6) {};
        \node [style={circulo_verde}] (15) at (11.5, 1) {};
        \node [style={circulo_verde}] (16) at (11.5, -0.5) {};
        \node [style={circulo_verde}] (17) at (11.5, -2) {};
        \node [style={circulo_vermelho}] (18) at (15.5, 1) {};
        \node [style={circulo_vermelho}] (19) at (15.5, -0.5) {};
        \node [style={circulo_vermelho}] (20) at (15.5, -2) {};
        \node [style={circulo_vermelho}] (21) at (19.5, 1) {};
        \node [style={circulo_vermelho}] (22) at (19.5, -0.5) {};
        \node [style={circulo_vermelho}] (23) at (19.5, -2) {};
        \node [style={circulo_amarelo}] (24) at (23.25, 1) {};
        \node [style={circulo_amarelo}] (25) at (23.25, -0.5) {};
        \node [style={circulo_amarelo}] (26) at (23.25, -2) {};
        \node [style=texto] (27) at (0, 6.75) {Static Input Layer};
        \node [style=texto] (28) at (0, 6) {4 Units};
        \node [style=texto] (29) at (3.5, 6.75) {Static Dense Layer};
        \node [style=texto] (30) at (3.5, 6) {64 Units};
        \node [style=texto] (31) at (7, 6.75) {Static Dense Layer};
        \node [style=texto] (32) at (7, 6) {128 Units};
        \node [style=texto] (33) at (0, -1.25) {LSTM Input Layer};
        \node [style=texto] (34) at (0, -2) {24 Units};
        \node [style=texto] (35) at (7, -1.25) {LSTM Layer};
        \node [style=texto] (36) at (7, -2) {128 Units};
        \node [style=texto] (37) at (11.5, 2.75) {Concatenate Layer};
        \node [style=texto] (38) at (11.5, 2) {256 Units};
        \node [style=texto] (39) at (15.5, 2.75) {Static Dense Layer};
        \node [style=texto] (40) at (15.5, 2) {48 Units};
        \node [style=texto] (41) at (19.5, 2.75) {Static Dense Layer};
        \node [style=texto] (42) at (19.5, 2) {24 Units};
        \node [style=texto] (43) at (23.25, 2.75) {Output Layer};
        \node [style=texto] (44) at (23.25, 2) {12 Units};
        \draw [style=seta] (0) to (3);
        \draw [style=seta] (0) to (4);
        \draw [style=seta] (0) to (5);
        \draw [style=seta] (1) to (3);
        \draw [style=seta] (1) to (4);
        \draw [style=seta] (1) to (5);
        \draw [style=seta] (2) to (3);
        \draw [style=seta] (2) to (4);
        \draw [style=seta] (2) to (5);
        \draw [style=seta] (3) to (6);
        \draw [style=seta] (3) to (7);
        \draw [style=seta] (3) to (8);
        \draw [style=seta] (4) to (6);
        \draw [style=seta] (4) to (7);
        \draw [style=seta] (4) to (8);
        \draw [style=seta] (5) to (6);
        \draw [style=seta] (5) to (7);
        \draw [style=seta] (5) to (8);
        \draw [style=seta] (9) to (12);
        \draw [style=seta] (9) to (13);
        \draw [style=seta] (9) to (14);
        \draw [style=seta] (10) to (12);
        \draw [style=seta] (10) to (13);
        \draw [style=seta] (10) to (14);
        \draw [style=seta] (11) to (12);
        \draw [style=seta] (11) to (13);
        \draw [style=seta] (11) to (14);
        \draw [style=seta] (6) to (15);
        \draw [style=seta] (6) to (16);
        \draw [style=seta] (6) to (17);
        \draw [style=seta] (7) to (15);
        \draw [style=seta] (7) to (16);
        \draw [style=seta] (7) to (17);
        \draw [style=seta] (8) to (15);
        \draw [style=seta] (8) to (16);
        \draw [style=seta] (8) to (17);
        \draw [style=seta] (12) to (15);
        \draw [style=seta] (12) to (16);
        \draw [style=seta] (12) to (17);
        \draw [style=seta] (13) to (15);
        \draw [style=seta] (13) to (16);
        \draw [style=seta] (13) to (17);
        \draw [style=seta] (14) to (15);
        \draw [style=seta] (14) to (16);
        \draw [style=seta] (14) to (17);
        \draw [style=seta] (15) to (18);
        \draw [style=seta] (15) to (19);
        \draw [style=seta] (15) to (20);
        \draw [style=seta] (16) to (18);
        \draw [style=seta] (16) to (19);
        \draw [style=seta] (16) to (20);
        \draw [style=seta] (17) to (18);
        \draw [style=seta] (17) to (19);
        \draw [style=seta] (17) to (20);
        \draw [style=seta] (18) to (21);
        \draw [style=seta] (18) to (22);
        \draw [style=seta] (18) to (23);
        \draw [style=seta] (19) to (21);
        \draw [style=seta] (19) to (22);
        \draw [style=seta] (19) to (23);
        \draw [style=seta] (20) to (21);
        \draw [style=seta] (20) to (22);
        \draw [style=seta] (20) to (23);
        \draw [style=seta] (21) to (24);
        \draw [style=seta] (21) to (25);
        \draw [style=seta] (21) to (26);
        \draw [style=seta] (22) to (24);
        \draw [style=seta] (22) to (25);
        \draw [style=seta] (22) to (26);
        \draw [style=seta] (23) to (24);
        \draw [style=seta] (23) to (25);
        \draw [style=seta] (23) to (26);
        \draw [style=seta, in=135, out=45, loop] (12) to ();
        \draw [style=seta, in=135, out=45, loop] (13) to ();
        \draw [style=seta, in=135, out=45, loop] (14) to ();
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Parallel LSTM-MLP network}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Many problems here:

1 - If i try to scale the whole picture using `scale = 0.5`, i still get `Overfull \hbox (34.27876pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 140--141`

2 - Text overlapping above each node;

3 - In the blue nodes, arrows that start and end at those nodes are also overlapping with the nodes above them (or in the case of the first blue node, it overlaps with the `LSTM Layer 128 units` text).

Any ideas in how to fix these issues?

Comment: try `every node/.style={scale=0.5}`

Comment: Alternately, you can also use `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, transform shape]` to scale all the text accordingly.

Comment: There is also `every node/.style={font=\scriptsize}`.  See also the tikzscale package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not scale your image because resulted image will has inconsistent font size and pure formatting. Far better result is obtained by redrawing image where I would:

- reduce horizontal distances between nodes
- in nodes for layer description use `\footnotesize` fonts and text spread in several lines
- rename nodes so, that name consist `<layer name><number of node>`. By this change the arrows between nodes can be drawn in double loop:

```
\documentclass[numbers, preprint, review,
               12pt, sort&compress]{elsarticle}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                              % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[%scale=0.7, transform shape,
  C/.style = {circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=4mm},
Cin/.style = {C, fill=gray},   
 Cr/.style = {C, fill=red},    
 Cg/.style = {C, fill=green}, 
 Cy/.style = {C, fill=yellow}, 
 Cb/.style = {C, fill=blue},   
 Tx/.style = {font=\footnotesize\linespread{0.84}\selectfont, inner sep=0pt,
              align=center, above},
every edge/.style= {draw=gray, -Straight Barb, semithick}
                        ]
% nodes
\node [Cin] (I1) at (0, 5) {};
\node [Cin] (I2) at (0, 3.5) {};
\node [Cin] (I3) at (0, 2) {};

\node [Cr]  (A1) at (2, 5) {};
\node [Cr]  (A2) at (2, 3.5) {};
\node [Cr]  (A3) at (2, 2) {};
\node [Cr]  (B1) at (4, 5) {};
\node [Cr]  (B2) at (4, 3.5) {};
\node [Cr]  (B3) at (4, 2) {};

\node [Cg]  (C1) at (6, 1) {};
\node [Cg]  (C2) at (6, -0.5) {};
\node [Cg]  (C3) at (6, -2) {};

\node [Cin] (D1) at (8, 1) {};
\node [Cin] (D2) at (8, -0.5) {};
\node [Cin] (D3) at (8, -2) {};
\node [Cin] (E1) at (10, 1) {};
\node [Cin] (E2) at (10, -0.5) {};
\node [Cin] (E3) at (10, -2) {};

\node [Cy]  (O1) at (12, 1) {};
\node [Cy]  (O2) at (12, -0.5) {};
\node [Cy]  (O3) at (12, -2) {};


\node [Cr]  (J1) at (0, -3) {};
\node [Cr]  (J2) at (0, -4.5) {};
\node [Cr]  (J3) at (0, -6) {};

\node [Cb]  (G1) at (4, -3) {};
\node [Cb]  (G2) at (4, -4.5) {};
\node [Cb]  (G3) at (4, -6) {};

\node [Tx]  at (0, 5.5)   {Static\\ Input\\ Layer\\ 4 Units};
\node [Tx]  at (2, 5.5)   {Static\\ Dense\\ Layer\\ 64 Units};
\node [Tx]  at (4, 5.5)   {Static\\ Dense\\ Layer\\ 128 Units};
\node [Tx]  at (0, -2)   {LSTM\\   Input\\ Layer\\ 24 Units};
\node [Tx]  at (4, -2)   {LSTM\\ Layer\\ 128 Units};
\node [Tx]  at (6, 2)    {Concatenate\\ Layer\\ 256\\ Units};
\node [Tx]  at (8, 2)    {Static\\ Dense\\ Layer\\ 48 Units};
\node [Tx]  at (10, 2)    {Static\\ Dense\\ Layer\\ 24 Units};
\node [Tx]  at (12, 2)    {Output\\ Layer\\ 12 Units};
% arrows
\foreach \m in {1,2,3}
    \foreach \n in {1,2,3}
    {
        \draw   (I\m) edge (A\n) 
                (A\m) edge (B\n) 
                (B\m) edge (C\n) 
                (C\m) edge (D\n) 
                (D\m) edge (E\n) 
                (E\m) edge (O\n) % output
    %
                (J\m) edge (G\n) 
                (G\m) edge (C\n) 
    %
                (G\n) edge [in=135, out=45, loop] ();
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Parallel LSTM-MLP network}
\label{fig:enter-label}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If image is to tall, than reduce vertical distance between nodes (for example from 1.5 to 1, or what you prefer that they should be)

Answer (score 1):

Answer based on Zarko's. You can adjust the spacing with `dx` and `dy`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
   
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  C/.style = {circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=4mm},
 C1/.style = {C, fill=red},  C2/.style = {C, fill=blue},    
 C3/.style = {C, fill=green},C4/.style = {C, fill=gray}, 
 C5/.style = {C, fill=gray}, C6/.style = {C, fill=yellow},   
 C7/.style = {C, fill=gray}, C8/.style = {C, fill=red},   
 C9/.style = {C, fill=red},  
 Tx/.style = {font=\footnotesize\linespread{0.84}\selectfont, inner sep=0pt,
              align=center, above},
every edge/.style= {draw=gray, -Straight Barb, semithick} ]

\def\dx{2}
\def\dy{1.5}
\foreach \i/\j/\n/\lab [count=\ST] in {
      0/0/J/{LSTM\\ Input\\ Layer\\ 24 Units},
      2*\dx/0/G/{LSTM\\ Layer\\ 128 Units},
      3*\dx/4/C/{Concatenate\\ Layer\\ 256\\ Units},
      4*\dx/4/D/{Static\\ Dense\\ Layer\\ 48 Units},
      5*\dx/4/E/{Static\\ Dense\\ Layer\\ 24 Units},
      6*\dx/4/O/{Output\\ Layer\\ 12 Units},
      0/8/I/{Static\\ Input\\ Layer\\ 4 Units},
      \dx/8/A/{Static\\ Dense\\ Layer\\ 64 Units},
      2*\dx/8/B/{Static\\ Dense\\ Layer\\ 128 Units}}
{\foreach \k in {1,2,3} {\node[C\ST](\n\k) at (\i,\j+\dy*\k) {};}
\node[anchor=south,above=2em,text width=2cm] at (\n3){\lab};
}

\foreach \m in {1,2,3}
    \foreach \n in {1,2,3}
    {   \draw   (I\m) edge (A\n)
                (A\m) edge (B\n)
                (B\m) edge (C\n)
                (C\m) edge (D\n)
                (D\m) edge (E\n)
                (E\m) edge (O\n) 
                (J\m) edge (G\n)
                (G\m) edge (C\n)
                (G\n) edge [in=135, out=45, loop] ();
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Parallel LSTM-MLP network}
\label{fig:enter-label}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]